# How to convert string in parent to proptype.number for React child component?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am sending `latitude` and `longitude`:

```
<ListItem
   title="Endereço"
   rightTitle={location ? location : '-'}
   hideChevron
   onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Maps', {latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude})}
 />
```

This sends ok, but the child component is waiting for a `proptype.number` while my parent is sending a string type.

How do I convert my props `latitude` and `longitude` to numbers?

Comment: `{latitude: +latitude, longitude: +longitude}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built in JavaScript `Number()` function.  Assuming the code you are showing is the parent, just wrap the string values in `Number()`:

```
<ListItem
   title="Endereço"
   rightTitle={location ? location : '-'}
   hideChevron
   onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Maps', {latitude: Number(latitude), longitude: Number(longitude)})}
 />
```

There are other ways to do this also, but this method has the advantage of clearly communicating your intention.

Comment: Thanks. How to achieve other ways ? not using Number js function.

Comment: @KumarRamalingam using the `Number()` function is probably the best way semantically.  There are more concise but less clear ways to achieve this in JavaScript for sure, but at the cost of creating more cryptic code.